# Looking for a graph with the biggest absolute eigenvalue of adjacency matrix negative.

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

In my class, our teacher define the spectral radius to be the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix, while I find in wiki that the spectral radius is defined as the largest absolute eigenvalues. So I wonder whether there is a counterexample. These examples in class, including complete graphs, circles, complete bipartite graphs don't work.

Comment: The spectral radius of a non-negative matrix is equal to its largest eigenvalue. Google Perron-Frobenius.

Comment: Thanks. It actually answers my question.